# Inspect element in Cypress test runner

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, cypress

I am relatively new to Cypress so this question may have an obvious answer but...

Has anyone noticed that the DOM looks different when inspecting an element from chrome using the cypress test runner?

For example:

when I open chrome normally and I click on a table then inspect element, it shows in the DOM with an associated data-e2e attribute. It also contains standard html table tags.

when I run 'npx cypress open' and inspect the same element from the test runner chrome, the same element does not have a data-e2e attribute. Also, the standard table tags are replaced with angular kendo tags.

This happens when I'm running the application locally.

The table is dynamically loaded with data retrieved from an api call, so maybe that's why it's different? Still, I'm wondering if I can retrieve that table by data-e2e attribute without the test failing because the test runner cannot find it.

Anyone have any idea where to begin?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.